# Как превратить "py" файл в ".exe" файл БЕЗ pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Написал сегодня небольшой прикол для друга на Пайтоне, и надо как понимаете превратить его из ".py" в ".exe", потому что у друга нету Пайтона на компьютере. Когда пробовал с помощью pyinstaller, мне в консоли писало - "pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом(Я его устанавливал, переходил в нужную директорию). Можно-ли либо pyinstaller починить, либо как-то по другому? Я новичок, и если можно, пожалуйста объясните чуть проще.

Comment: да, надо просто переписать на языке, который умеет "компилироваться". Все остальное - полумеры.

Comment: Как именно вы устанавливали pyinstaller? Пробовали ли вы запустить pyinstaller через [флаг -m](https://docs.python.org/3.10/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) вот так `python -m pyinstaller your_file.py`?